# How I can have transform animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Here I got 2 shapes, one Rectangle and one Circle, which with action of a Button only one of them became visible to user, I tried to use @Namespace for this transform, but did not panned out!

**MY Goal: Having a nice and smooth transform animation from one Shape to other.**

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var action: Bool = false
@Namespace var sameShape

var body: some View {
    
    
    ZStack
    {
        
        Group
        {
            if action
            {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue).frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Dakota148Zero", in: sameShape)
            }
            else
            {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red).frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Dakota148Zero", in: sameShape)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        
        
        
        VStack
        {
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("transform") { action.toggle() }.font(Font.largeTitle).padding()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out, it's really cool - https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part1/

Answer (score 3):

Here is way to do it by representing the circle and square as a `RoundedRectangle` with different `cornerRadius` values:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var action = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack
        {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: action ? 0 : 75)
                .fill(action ? Color.red : .blue)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            
            VStack
            {
                Spacer()
                
                Button("transform") {
                    action.toggle()
                }
                .font(Font.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: demo in simulator]

Comment: thanks a lot, that was first thing I thought about it! LoL But I am looking for decent transform animation

Comment: With mine solution and this being here, I'm wondering what is a "decent transform animation" that these two solutions are not? @Omar

Comment: @IiroAlhonen, yes it gives the illusion of transform, but I can not use this cornerRadios to transform to an other shape like Star, the point of my question is the transform animation, not solving an example of it

Answer (score 2):

`Group` is not real container, so don't store animation. Replace `Group` with some stack, like

```
        VStack
        {
            if action
              // ... other code no change
```

Comment: Agreed. Replace Group with ZStack and it should work.

Comment: I already made the changes no success! even used withAnimation in Button, nothing

Answer (score 2):

With iOS14 out, you can use matchedGeometryEffect(). If you are using iOS14, I would recommend this approach.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-synchronize-animations-from-one-view-to-another-with-matchedgeometryeffect

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)

So in your solution, if you replace `action.toggle()` with `withAnimation{self.action.toggle()}` in your button code, it will animate.

```
Button("transform") { 
    withAnimation{self.action.toggle()} 
    }
.font(Font.largeTitle).padding()
```

This solution works on the simulator for me (Xcode 12.1, iPhone 11 iOS 14.1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var action: Bool = false
@Namespace var transition

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Group {
            if action {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue).frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "shape", in: transition)
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red).frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "shape", in: transition)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Button("transform") { withAnimation{self.action.toggle()} }.font(Font.largeTitle).padding()
                
        }
    }
}
}
```

The matchedGeometryEffect() doesn't want to animate different shapes (including cornerRadius) or colors that nicely, not sure if this is a bug that will get fixed in future patches or just a feature that needs to be worked around by regular animations. With me playing around with matchedGeometryEffect(), it seems to do great with sizing things up and down, like shown with this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var animate: Bool = false
@Namespace private var transition

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if animate {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 75.0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "shape", in: transition)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        animate.toggle()
                    }
         
            } else {
                // Circle
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 75.0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "shape", in: transition)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        animate.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Omar Pasted the entire code that works for me in the simulator without issues.

Comment: I had the same result before asking this question, look the code and animation of @vacawama he got the right effect but it is not transform animation or kind of that, he works with cornerRadius

Comment: @Omar now I got really interested, so will do some more research.

Comment: Yes! This Topic is very hard, I wanted build a custom animation, but it would working only and only for transform from Circle to Rectangle or from Rectangle to Circle! but what about other Shapes! like transform from a Rectangle to Pentagon or to a Star! I got an idea to work on, and it is working on path of shape, actually it is very hard and big project, I believe it would be better working with Metal or SpritKit for a general Animation usage.  But for sure the way to go maybe is path and core Graphic

Comment: @Omar I played around with the code a bit more, and it for sure seems to be that you need to work with cornerRadiuses (or paths of shapes) to make the animation work smoothly. I added a small code block to demonstrate what I found that matchedGeometryAnimation does best. Make sure to share us a solution if you write one.

Comment: Definitely, this question could be a reason to jump on pool of Metal and see what is going there as well.